# Why casting JSONTokener To JSONObject doesn't work on my codes?

Tags: android, json

I'm new on Android programming and want to do some casting type.

After some searching i saw every body use this sample codes very easily on their samples and apps but when i want to use it on my sample app it doesn't work .

I'm so wondering of this, what is wrong with my codes?

```
 String temp = output;//output contains some string type data
 JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(temp).nextValue();
```

I'm using

```
Android Studio 2.1.2 
Android API 23 (Android 6 Marshallow)
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

picture of codes and error on Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: It's not error Just put it in **try-catch** block; Also may you need https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Thanks a lot Amir, when i put my codes on try-catch block red line  disappeared, I'm wondering of this damn IDE

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks a lot Amir (first comment), when i put my codes on try-catch block red line  disappeared, I'm wondering of this damn IDE**

*Google should fix somethings like this*

```
   try {        
        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener("xxxx").nextValue();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("xxxx",e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: This is a feature not bug my friend

Comment: LOL ,a feature, this feature wasted my time, then this is not a good feature, from where i had to know that i should use try.... ha? I did some search but there is no help about this magical feature,THEN THIS IS A BUG